# Import turn.js in ionic 2 project

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have literally searched and tried every single solution out there to include 3rd party javascript files/libraries that is not supported by npm, in ionic 2 projects. Nothing worked for me. Is there a best practice for this purpose or any self-explanatory tutorials available? Can anyone suggest a solution to include turn.js in ionic 2 projects?

Answer (score 1):

If you search for `turn.js` on npmjs.com you will find it as the first entry there. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turn.js) is a link.

But I do not recommend you using such an old and probably unmaintained library. You will also need jQuery for it which will be a real downer for size/performance of your app. Also some users mentioned in the [github issues](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues) that it does not work on some modern browsers and that problems on mobile devices exist. You can try [this](https://github.com/marvindanig/flippy.JS) alternative solution, though I don't know how well it works. And [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/#using-libraries) you can find the offical ionic docs on how to work with third-party-libs.

Comment: Do you think jquery mobile would be a better alternative? I really love ionic but I don't want to lose all the pre-written libraries of javascript.

Comment: No you should not use jQuery in an ionic project at all. It is based on typescript/angular and should be written in such. You can if course use third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your advice